# calculating amount of months needed to save for house down payment

Tags: python

Write a program to calculate how many months it will take you save up enough money for a downpayment.  Like before, assume that your investments earn a return of r = 0.04 (or 4%) and the
required down payment percentage is 0.25 (or 25%).  Have the user enter the following variables:

1. The starting annual salary (annual_salary)
2. The percentage of salary to be saved (portion_saved)
3. The cost of your dream home (total_cost)
4. The semi­annual salary raise (semi_annual_raise)em

This should be the right results:
But **My program passes the first test but off by one month in other two, I can't find a solution**

Test Case 1

```
Enter your starting annual salary: 120000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .05
Enter the cost of your dream home: 500000
Enter the semi­annual raise, as a decimal: .03
Number of months: 142
```

Test Case 2

```
Enter your starting annual salary: 80000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .1
Enter the cost of your dream home: 800000
Enter the semi­annual raise, as a decimal: .03
Number of months: 159
```

Test Case 3

```
Enter your starting annual salary: 75000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .05
Enter the cost of your dream home: 1500000
Enter the semi­annual raise, as a decimal: .05
Number of months: 261
```

Code:

```
annual_salary = int(input("Salary: "))
portion_saved = float(input("Percentage to save: ")) 
total_cost = int(input("Cost of the house: "))
portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
current_savings = 0
rate = 0.04
number_of_months = 0
semi_annual_raise = float(input("Raise: "))

while current_savings <= portion_down_payment:
    current_savings += annual_salary * portion_saved / 12
    current_savings += current_savings * rate / 12
    number_of_months += 1
    if number_of_months % 6 == 0:
        annual_salary += annual_salary * semi_annual_raise
    print(number_of_months, current_savings)

print("Enter your annual salary: ", annual_salary)  
print("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: ", portion_saved)
print("Enter the cost of your dream home: ", total_cost) 
print("Number of months: ", number_of_months)
```

Comment: it's a floating decimal precision problem within, try converting using int() or maybe tuple() at the later stages, a lot of financial calculators are actually 'modded' to be 'precisely inaccurate' to correct for this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, what are the right answers, and what debugging traces have you run?
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I get results of 142, 158, and 260 for the three runs.  I'm using Python 3.5.2

Comment: yes i get the same results but they suppose to be 142, 159, 261. I guess oliver is right its a floating decimal precision problem

Comment: Try using the decimal module for arbitrary-precision calulations.

Answer (score 0):

while current_savings < Down_payment :

it should be this, this is why you are one-off

Comment: Try to send it as a comment.